# CSS inline Div invisible spacing?

Tags: html, css

Been trying to get these div's to line up along side of each other without there being that space in between them. Not really sure what's happening... I have tried everything and I just can't figure out what this is... I know it is a simple fix but it just doesn't seem to want to work. The weird thing is there are times that I am messing around with the live code on Chrome and it magically seems to work momentarily...

Any help is appreciated.

**Here is my fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/2jL5D/

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-Container">
    <div id="fan-free-container">
        FAN-FREE AND ENERGY EFFICIENT<br>
        <div id="seriesContainer">
            <div id="tx4200Container"><div class="txHeader">TX4200E</div></div>
            <div id="ks6700Container"><div class="ksHeader">KS6700</div></div>
            <div id="ks7200Container"><div class="ksHeader">KS7200</div></div>
            <div id="ks7500Container"><div class="ksHeader">KS7500</div></div>
            <div id="ks7700Container"><div class="ksHeader">KS7700</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fan-free-container {
    background: rgb(230,231,233);
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #c4c5c6;
    border-width: 2px;
}

#seriesContainer > div{
    display: inline-block;
}

#seriesContainer div > div{
    padding: 4px 25px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #c4c5c6;
    border-width: 2px;
}

.txHeader {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#af9358, #ded1b9); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#af9358, #ded1b9); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#af9358, #ded1b9); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#af9358, #ded1b9); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

.ksHeader {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#06426b, #93a7c2); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#06426b, #93a7c2); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#06426b, #93a7c2); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#06426b, #93a7c2); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Comment: Just search a little on google the answer is here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2jL5D/1/

Comment: @NinjaFart what did you do?

Comment: @metsales I just put all the DIV's into one line.

Comment: @NinjaFart so it's basically taking the new line character and turning it into whitespace?

Comment: @metsales Well, something like that. You've also got space before every DIV.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space so you can just eliminate the space between the divs like in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2jL5D/2/)**.

You can also use HTML comments between them like: `</div><!--     --></div>`. **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GYc5Z/)**